# Applescript access Safari's "Reload this page" button update

Tags: safari, applescript, pageload

Classic problem: Wait until the webpage has fully loaded and rendered in Safari.

Most snippets I found date years back and of course macOS and Safari have been upgraded, so I am looking how to TARGET this `Reload this page` button

I am on ****macOS Big Sur 11.7.2**** with ****Safari v16.2****, attached a screenshot (Note the beta Translate button)

[image]

This snipped should have been working on **macOS High Sierra**

```
tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:"https://nytimes.com"}
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (accessibility description of ¬
        button 1 of UI element 2 of every group of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
        process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page") contains "Reload this page"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
log "Finished loading"
```

I tried to change `button 1 of UI element 2` to `button 2` assuming button 1 could be the Translate button but no go.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, I just found it, with a better Google search, on
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424629/applescript-to-prompt-for-url-input-open-url-in-safari-then-open-bookmark-with

So just for a reference:

```
tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:"https://nytimes.com"}
my waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()

to waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Wait for page to finish loading in Safari.
    --  # This works in **macOS Catalina** and 
    --  # macOS Big Sur and may need adjusting for
    --  # other versions of macOS.
    log "page is loading...."
    tell application "System Events" to repeat until ¬
        exists (buttons of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    log "page is LOADED"
end waitForSafariPageToFinishLoading
```